# how to update Document in doc set

Tags: development, client-object-model, document, document-set, updatelistitems

I've been trying to update the file name of a document inside of a doc set. I continually get either a "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only." error or an "item is checked out to ..." error

Here is what I'm trying:

```
        foreach (Folder folder in documentsList.RootFolder.Folders)
        {
            clientContext.Load(folder.Files);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in folder.Files)
            {
                if (file.Name == xfileName)
                {
                    file.ListItemAllFields["Document_x0020_Type"] = docType;
                    file.ListItemAllFields["LinkFilename"] = documentName;
                    file.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                    file.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);

                }

            }
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

I've also tried:

```
                foreach (Folder folder in documentsList.RootFolder.Folders)
                {
                    clientContext.Load(folder.Files);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in folder.Files)
                    {
                        if (file.Name == xfileName)
                        {
file.CheckOut();
                            file.ListItemAllFields["Document_x0020_Type"] = docType;
                            file.ListItemAllFields["LinkFilename"] = documentName;
                            file.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                            file.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        }

                    }

                }
```

I can't seem to get this to work... Any help would be appreciated!